# If statement in a setInterval function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, google-tag-manager

I have the following code. What I am trying to achieve is to count the seconds where {{UTL - Visibility hidden}} == true when it is false. {{UTL - Visibility hidden}} is a macro that determines whether the browser tab is open, so it checks every second, and adds a second to the total sum of 'time on' or 'time off'.

However when I run this, it is taking the state when the page loads, and is not checking every second and changing the if statement. My assumption is that every second the function would run, evaluate whether {{UTL - Visibility hidden}} == false, and run the relevant section.

Do I have the order wrong? Is there a more effective way to do this?

```
x=0
y=0
setInterval(function () {
  if({{UTL - Visibility hidden}} == false){
    dataLayer.push({
        'event' : 'Timer test',
      'time on' : x
       }); 
  x=x+1
}
else{
    dataLayer.push({
         'event' : 'Timer test',
      'time off' : y
      }); 
  y=y+1  
}}

  , 1000);
```

The macro is generated in Google Tag Manager from the following javascript:

UTL - Visibility hidden

```
    function() {
      switch ({{UTL - Visibility prefix}}) {
        case '':
          return document['hidden'];
        case 'moz':
          return document['mozHidden'];
        case 'o':
          return document['oHidden'];
        case 'webkit':
          return document['webkitHidden'];
        default:
          return;
      }
    }
```

UTL - Visability prefix

```
function() {
  var prefixes = ['moz', 'ms', 'o', 'webkit'];

  if ('hidden' in document) {
    return '';
  }

  // Loop through each prefix to see if it is supported.
  for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
    var testPrefix = prefixes[i] + 'Hidden';
    if (testPrefix in document) {
      return prefixes[i];
    }
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: Where does that macro come from…? Where/what/when is evaluating that?

Comment: If that is literally the contents of the macros, then the generated code is `if( function() { ... } == false )`. You're comparing the function definition to false instead of calling it and comparing the return value. Perhaps `if(({{UTL - Visibility hidden}})() == false)`? It would help if you could show the generated JS.